# Laravel checking articles older than a certain date

Tags: php, laravel

In a project I have been working on, I have an area to upload articles. I used Faker to generate 2,500 articles as I was aiming to test performance. I came to the conclusion that I should cull articles older than x days or months old.

The articles I have all have a published status: `published', 'draft' and 'archived', this is stored in an articles database table.

I am going to build a scheduled task, that will run monthly to check for old articles and then set these articles to archived.

In Laravel I know I could do something like this:

```
$articles = Article::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(182));
$articles->published = 'archived';
$articles->save();
```

But essentially what I'm after is the equivalent of:

`UPDATE articles SET published = 'archived' WHERE created_at > <6 months>`

This is probably really very simple and perhaps I'm just overcomplicating but I've been staring at this for literally 90 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `where` clauses in an update method like so:

```
Article::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(6))->update(['published' => 'archived']);
```

This assumes your `published` property is fillable. It's also worth noting that this method will not trigger any eloquent events.

Comment: My `published` property is fillable, yes. Elequent events are on trigged on the use of `save()` are they not?

Comment: @JesseOrange I was saying eloquent events won't fire with my answer.

Comment: @jfadich, your where operator is incorrect. It should be `<=`. Otherwise you're archiving all articles less than 6 months old.

Comment: @fubar I fixed it

Comment: @JesseOrange Did this fix your problem?